# I already SMS module create in Tally Developer 9.Working Properly but my requirement is multiple item select than message not proper way

Tags: tally

single item select:-
Example: "Dear Sir, your sales item name is mobile and price 100 Rs."

Multiple items select:- "Dear Sir, your sales item name is mobile, price 100 Rs 1 qty and laptop price  10000 Rs 1 qty"